# Can I ask networking vender's product information there?

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about bellow list:

```
Juniper vSRX NG 17.3, 18.X
Juniper vMX 14.1.4R8
Juniper vMX 16.1R3.10, 17.X, 18.X VCP (control plane node)
Juniper vMX 16.1R3.10, 17.X, 18.X VFP (forwarding plane node)
Juniper vMX 17.1, 17.2, 17.3 VCP (control plane node)
Juniper vMX 17.1, 17.2, 17.3 VFP (forwarding plane node)
Juniper vQFX 10K VRE 15.1X53, 17.X (routing engine)
Juniper vQFX 10K VFE 15.1X53, 17.X (forwarding engine)
Juniper VRR
```

I want to know the meanings difference of `vSRX`, `vMX`, `vQFX`, `VRR`, `vQFX 10K VRE`, `vQFX 10K VFE`, `VCP`, `VFP`. can I ask this type question in NE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely, yes. Although I must say that you could probably find out the differences between most of these virtual devices on the Juniper site, since (v)SRX, (v)VMX and (v)QFX are described in detail there.